# React state hook Object not updating, getting [Object object]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, state

In my project I am having trouble setting a state variable with a javascript object, I can see in my console logs that the object is being instansiated correctly with the right values, but I cannot figure out why it is not properly setting the state hook.

Any help would be appreciate!!

```js
const [accountInfo, setAccountInfo] = useState({})

const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

const onLogin = async (account) => {

    await(delay(2000));

    console.log(account); // I am getting the proper output of the object here

    if(account.account_id != -1){

      setAccountInfo(account);

      await delay(4000); //Just for debugging
      console.log("acc " + accountInfo); // This outputs [Object object]
      setLoggedIn(true);
    }else{
      alert('Account does not exist');
    }
  }
```

Comment: `accountInfo` is an object. If you want to convert an object to a string use `JSON.stringify( accountInfo )`

Comment: It is still in the base state when the state hook was set, in console.log Ill get `[Object object]` or if I use `JSON.Stringify` ill get `{}`

Comment: Note that after `setAccountInfo`, `accountInfo` will not be updated until the next render, and will not immediately be updated after the call to `setAccountInfo`.  You can use the local `account` variable though.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to concatenate string with object. Either convert object to string with JSON.stringify or use object.property.

```
console.log("Object" + JSON.stringify(object_to_print));
```

you are trying to console.log a state variable. React is not guaranteeing the state change immediately. you can access state change in useEffect hook

```
useEffect(() => { 
      console.log('state changed', your-state-variable) 
      // write your callback function here
 }, [your-state-variable]);
```

Comment: Either way it still doesnt work, If I console.log just the object it is still empty, or if I stringify I get `{}`